# Is it possible to give "out-of-the-box" programs an executable command in Linux?

Tags: linux, tar, portable

I don't know if I'm being clear. Take the following scenario:

You have downloaded a .tar.gz compressed program, you unpack it, and it runs right from there. It's not source code, just an application that doesn't need an installation to run.

Let's say I want this application (let's call it ProgramZ) to run with a terminal command `programz` (or Alt+F2, whatever, ) from any directory in my Linux box.

Is that even possible? Do I have to copy the executable to /bin? If so, is that enough? If not, how do I properly do it without risking my system's stability?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not required to copy the file to /bin directory. You may either copy it into the /usr/bin directory or create a symlink like so `ln -s /path/to/exec /usr/bin/progname`. You might need to use `sudo` according to your configuration. Symbolic linking is better under most of the circumstances. And don't forget to `chmod +x progfile` to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to give the full path to run something.

If the executable/binary (what you call "out-of-the-box") `prg` is located in `/home/bla/` you say `/home/bla/prg`.

Or if you already are in `/home/bla` you have to say `./prg` (unless `/home/bla` is contained within the path (`echo $PATH`).